# How to quickly split a data.table in R based on factor column into a list?

Tags: r, list, split, data.table, data-manipulation

an example with required result (achieved by hard-coding)

```
DT <- data.table(val=1:8, f=c('a','b','b','a','b','a','a','c'))  
required <- list(DT[f=='a'], DT[f=='b'], DT[f=='c'])
```

Comment: There's a `split` method for data.tables. `split(DT, by='f')` should do it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas and the reverse is `rbindlist`?

Comment: Yes, it is. `rbindlist(split(DT, by='f'))` gives the original `DT` with the rows in order a,b,c.

Comment: @RuiBarradas please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `split` method for objects of class `"data.table"`. But unlike in base R's method for data.frames, there is an argument `by` that needs quoted column names.

From `help('split.data.table')`, my emphasis:

> Details
> Argument f is just for consistency in usage to data.frame method. **Recommended is to use by argument instead**, it will be faster, more flexible, and by default will preserve order according to order in data.

```
split(DT, by = 'f')
#$a
#   val f
#1:   1 a
#2:   4 a
#3:   6 a
#4:   7 a
#
#$b
#   val f
#1:   2 b
#2:   3 b
#3:   5 b
#
#$c
#   val f
#1:   8 c
```

The reverse is `rbindlist`. It gives the original DT with the rows in order `a`, `b`, `c`.

```
rbindlist(split(DT, by = 'f'))
#   val f
#1:   1 a
#2:   4 a
#3:   6 a
#4:   7 a
#5:   2 b
#6:   3 b
#7:   5 b
#8:   8 c
```